# What does the phrase 'holding in the palm of hands' in chinese mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase, idioms, phrase-request

I've read that phrase in a lot of stories and in a lot of different form; could you tell me the official form of that phrase (or maybe idiom) and its meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The common word is  [掌握](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5866/) (hold in one's palm) meaning " **have possession and control of something**"

Example:

**掌握**軍國大權 (**hold control** of the government and the armed force)

**掌握**有力證據 (**holding**/ **have possession** of powerful evidence)

There's also an idiom 
**玩弄於股掌之上** (to toy with someone on one's thighs and palms)- meaning: " **play someone like a fiddle**"

Another idiom mentioned "in the palm" is  "**掌上明珠**" (pearl in one's palm). It means " **treasured daughter**"

Comment: what about phrase/idiom 'like a treasure in one's palm' or something similar?

Comment: Please see edition.

Answer (score 1):

it is a setence of a poem wrote by William Blake.the whole poem is:
To see a world in a grain of sand. And a heaven in a wild flower Hold infinity in the palm of your hand .And eternity in an hour.

its chinese translation is
在一颗沙粒中见一个世界，
在一朵鲜花中见一片天空，
在你的掌心里把握无限，
在一个钟点里把握无穷。

Comment: OP wrote: "I've read that phrase in a lot of stories and in a lot of different form..." -- I am sure he wanted to know the general meaning of " holding in the palm of hands"  in Chinese. The same phrase appears in a poem is immaterial to the question.

Comment: By the way, "Hold infinity in the palm of your hand" can be translated as "把无限掌握在手中"

Comment: @TangHo I just cited it from an book which an professional person translated it

Comment: Different professional translate differently. My translation is no less accurate than the one you cited. To be honest, We can often find poorly translated materials made it to the publications.

Comment: For example: "wild flower" should be translated as 野花;  " eternity" should be translated as 永恒,  This  professional translator's work is quite sloppy if you ask me.